# MySQL left join populating value in absence of data

Tags: mysql

Trying to set up a stored proc for use with a multi-series chart and need date value populated for each customer for each date in the range submitted (variables passed IN) even when there is no transaction data for that customer on a particular date.

I have a query like this:

```
select 
Customer.Name
, sum(if(Transaction.StopTime > Transaction.StartTime, Transaction.StopTime - Transaction.StartTime,0)) as TimeSpent
, Transaction.Date

from Customer

left outer join Transaction ON Transaction.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID 
    and Transaction.Date >= str_to_date(DateFrom,'%m/%d/%Y')
    and Transaction.Date <= str_to_date(DateTo,'%m/%d/%Y')

group by Customer.Name, Transaction.Date
```

That returns something like this:

```
Name | TimeSpent | Date  
------------------------------
john | 6          | 2014-03-01 
mary | 12         | 2014-03-01 
john | 0          | NULL  
mary | 12         | 2014-03-02 
john | 4          | 2014-03-03 
mary | 0          | NULL
```

Is there a way to get the dates to populate on all rows via subquery or looping through the values of the variables passed?

Like this:

```
Name | TimeSpent | Date  
------------------------------
john | 6          | 2014-03-01 
mary | 12         | 2014-03-01 
john | 0          | 2014-03-02  
mary | 12         | 2014-03-02 
john | 4          | 2014-03-03 
mary | 0          | 2014-03-03
```

Comment: you want a custom value for date ??

Comment: Want date populated for all rows, added desired outcome to end of post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `cross join` to get all possible dates in the range.  Then you can use this field for the `left join` and in the `select`:

```
select c.Name,
       sum(if(t.StopTime > t.StartTime, t.StopTime - t.StartTime,0)) as TimeSpent,
       td.Date
from Customer c cross join
     (select distinct t.date
      from Transaction t 
      where t.Date >= str_to_date(DateFrom, '%m/%d/%Y') and
            t.Date <= str_to_date(DateTo, '%m/%d/%Y')
     ) td left outer join
     Transaction t
     ON t.CustomerID = c.CustomerID and
        t.date = td.date
group by c.Name, td.Date;
```

On another note, you should get in the habit of prefixing variables such as `DateFrom` with something (like `v_DateFrom`) so they are not confused with columns in tables.

Comment: This will work as long as at least one transaction exists for each date.

Comment: CROSS JOIN - duh!  This seems to be working exactly as hoped - thank you!